# IOException Was Unhandled Error Help for Newbie

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010, ioexception

You'll have to excuse me for a repeat question but I just can't seem to understand the responses others have been posting. My coding skills are very limited (barely a year in vb 2006 and vs 2010) 
I know that the sr has opened too many of the same file but I cant figure out a fix for it. Explaining it to me in simple concepts would be very helpful. Once again sorry for the newby-ness.

Project Explanation: Create a bowling league stats keeper. cmdRegisterBowler adds bowler name to a dat file (bowlers.dat). cmdEnterScores will write name and stats to games.dat file.

```
    Private Sub cmdRegisterBowler_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdRegisterBowler.Click

    'BOWLER REGISTRATION

    Dim Person As String
    Dim Team As String

    txtName.Text.ToUpper()
    txtTeam.Text.ToUpper()

    Person = txtName.Text
    Team = txtTeam.Text

    If Person <> "" And Team <> "" Then

        If IsInFile(Person & " " & Team) = True Then

            MessageBox.Show(Person & " is already in the file.", "Error")
            txtName.Clear()
            txtTeam.Clear()
            txtName.Focus()

        Else

            'swb = stream writer bowlers file
            Dim swb As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.AppendText("bowlers.dat")
            swb.WriteLine(Person & " " & Team)
            swb.Close()

            MessageBox.Show(Person & " has been added to the file.", "Information Added")
            txtName.Clear()
            txtTeam.Clear()
            txtName.Focus()

        End If

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a name.", "Information Incomplete")
    End If


End Sub
Function IsInFile(ByVal person As String) As String
    If IO.File.Exists("bowlers.dat") Then
        Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("bowlers.dat")
        Dim individual As String
        Do Until sr.EndOfStream
            individual = sr.ReadLine
            If individual = person Then

                Return True
                sr.Close()
            End If
        Loop
        sr.Close()
    End If
    Return False

End Function

Private Sub cmdEnterScores_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdEnterScores.Click

    'SCORE ENTRY

    Dim Person As String
    Dim Team As String
    Dim Score1 As Double
    Dim Score2 As Double
    Dim Score3 As Double
    Dim Average As Double
    Dim Display As String = "{0,-10} {1,10} {2,20} {3,10} {4,10} {5,10} {6,10}"
    Dim Total As Double

    Person = txtName2.Text
    Team = txtTeam2.Text
    Score1 = Val(txtFirstGame.Text)
    Score2 = Val(txtSecondGame.Text)
    Score3 = Val(txtThirdGame.Text)
    Total = Score1 + Score2 + Score3
    Average = Total / 3
    Dim swb As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.AppendText("bowlers.dat")

    'Checks for blank entries 
    If Person <> "" Then

        'Checks to see if person is registered
        If IsNotInFile(Person) Then

            Dim Response As Integer

            ' Displays a message box with the yes and no options to register bowler.
            Response = MsgBox(Prompt:="The bowler you have entered is currently not registered. Would you like to do so?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)

            'Yes button was selected. Bowler is then registered to bowlers.dat
            If Response = vbYes Then

                ''swb = stream writer bowlers file
                swb.WriteLine(Person & " " & Team)
                swb.Close()
                MessageBox.Show(Person & " has been added to the file.", "Information Added")

                'The no button was selected. Focus is set to bowler registration group box
            Else : Response = vbNo
                txtName2.Clear()
                txtTeam2.Clear()
                txtFirstGame.Clear()
                txtSecondGame.Clear()
                txtThirdGame.Clear()
                txtName.Focus()
            End If

            'If no then clears score entry group box and sets focus back to bowler registr
            txtName.Clear()
            txtName.Focus()

        Else
            'Write scores to games.dat file
            'swg = stream writer games file 
            Dim swg As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.AppendText("games.dat")
            swg.WriteLine(Name & " " & Team & " " & Score1 & " " & Score2 & " " & Score3)
            swg.Close()

            MessageBox.Show(Person & "'s stats added to the file.", "Information Added")
            txtName.Clear()
            txtName.Focus()

            Dim Display2 As String = "{0,-10} {1,10} {2,20} {3,10} {4,10} {5,10} {6,10}"
            lstDisplay.Items.Add(String.Format(Display2, Person, Team, Score1, Score2, Score3, Total, Average))

        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter a name.", "Information Incomplete")
    End If


End Sub
Function IsNotInFile(ByVal person As String) As String
    If IO.File.Exists("bowlers.dat") Then
        Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("bowlers.dat")
        Dim individual As String
        Do Until sr.EndOfStream
            individual = sr.ReadLine
            If individual <> person Then

                Return True
                sr.Close()
            End If
        Loop
        sr.Close()
    End If
    Return False

End Function
```

Heres all my code. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you ask anything different this time? For example, I'm positive that if it were the identical question, someone would have told you to point out the line that the exception is occurring on.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Visual Basic in quite a while, but I believe the solution is simple.

Basically, your interactions with the System.IO library are currently very optimistic. You should always wrap IO interactions within a TRY...CATCH...END TRY block.

Check it out here: [MSDN Example of StreamReader.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

To illustrate more clearly my meaning, I've altered one of your functions here:

```vb
Function IsInFile(ByVal person As String) As String
    Try
        If IO.File.Exists("bowlers.dat") Then
            Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("bowlers.dat")
            Dim individual As String
            Do Until sr.EndOfStream
                individual = sr.ReadLine
                If individual = person Then

                    Return True
                    sr.Close()
                End If
            Loop
            sr.Close()
        End If
        Return False
    Catch ie as IOException
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to search for " & person & " in file.", "Error")
        Return false
    End Try
End Function
```

I'd apply similar logic to surround all your interactions with Files within your code. I'd also recommend against using MessageBox to report errors -- it's okay for small projects, but for anything larger you're going to want to look up using a [logging framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.logging.log%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Or build a debug console into your application that you can selective turn on or off via configuration.